# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input - Add Product in Cart in Page Product

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping

[image: Erro when a put product in cart in the product page]

```
VM82534:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getData (main.js:58)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDocument.apply (main.js:74)
    at fire (jquery.js:3239)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3298)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3549)
    at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2974)
    at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.js:241)
    at jQuery (jquery.js:80)
```

Comment: The problem occurs when I place the shipping error message contains a special character, in case it was apostrophe.

Comment: disable the Amazon_Core module and check again if working then tell me

Comment: I dont use Amazon_Core, I resolved by removing the apostrophe from the standard dispatch error message.